# Flexible resolution for Spotfire Dxps

Tags: spotfire

Is there a way to fix a single dxp file to different screen sizes ,for example i want to use same dxp to access from iphone,ipad and Moniter so it has to set automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to develop mobile analytics I strongly suggest you download the Spotfire App at the Google Play and [Apple Stores](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spotfire-analytics/id417436823?mt=8).  This will ensure your visualization is rendered properly and provides you with mobile touching features that you may find cumbersome attempting through a mobile web browser.

Before you start building your analytic, go to `Edit > Document Properties > Visualization area size` and select one of the iPad options, or set a custom size. You will see the window resize in the professional client, emulating what the mobile application would look like. Personally, I'd steer free of creating one for a phone. It's just unrealistic, so much so that Spotfire discontinued it's mobile analytics which was used for phones, because, in my opinion, it didn't have a ton of value. It's hard to gain a lot from a visualization so small.

Comment: once i set the visualization area and created a report and i tried to open it with small resolution screens it is messing up

Comment: @Rama Define "messing up"

Comment: means inserting some zoom sliders,reducing visualization size

Comment: All of those features are dynamic which is why you should use the mobile application for iPad. Also, it's VERY hard to know what each screen resolution will be set to in your environment. Even if you make sure they are all the same, the monitors themselves likely aren't all the same size, which will throw this off.